# Why is dataclasses.as_dict a function instead of a method

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I know I can convert a Python dataclass to a dictionary using the `asdict` function:

```
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass

@dataclass
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int

point = Point(1, 2)

asdict(point)
# {'x': 1, 'y': 2}
```

Why is `asdict` a separate function instead a method on the object? The method feels more Pythonic / intuitive and prevents what seems like an unnecessary import:

```
point.asdict()
# {'x': 1, 'y': 2}
```

Is there a specific reason for this design or did the authors just choose a function for no good reason? I'm curious because I'm wondering if there are any key design takeaways.

**Hypothesis**

One potential reason may be that injecting the method may override an existing method. For example, if `Point.asdict()` already exists on the vanilla class:

```
@dataclass
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int

    def asdict(self):
        return {"x": self.x, "y": self.y, "sum": self.x + self.y}
```

In this case, injecting `asdict` as a method would override the existing functionality.

Comment: `dataclass` is a function, not a type, so the decorated class wouldn't be inherited the method anyway; `dataclass` would have to attach the same function to the class. If you really wanted to, you could do the same: `Point.asdict = dataclasses.asdict`.

Comment: This was discussed early on in the development of the dataclasses proposal. Some of the relevant discussion can be found in [#8 - Module-level functions or instance methods for helpers](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses/issues/8).

Comment: @Brian: this, maybe with some quotes, should be the answer.